# default keyword with unique default value in mssql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, default-value, unique-constraint

I want to add a **Column** to a **table** in my `Database`. As several data already exist in that particular `table` , `MSSQL` does not allow me to add a not **Null** field. So I can use a default keyword to solve this problem and run the below mentioned `Query` -

```
  Alter table ServiceDetails 
  Add  OCF_Internal_ID varchar(50) not null default 'OCF';
```

But now I want to make the  `"OCF_Internal_ID"` field `Primary key` and I need to insert unique values to the every record of that particular filed. Please give me any suggestion.

How can I add Unique values to all the existing records ?

Comment: Why `varchar(50)` rather than numeric and `identity`? Or `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: Sounds like you don't care what the value is.  Why don't you modify the table and add a Int Identity Primary Key Clustered column instead of a varchar(50) which makes a poor primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these options

```
Alter table ServiceDetails 
  Add  OCF_Internal_ID integer NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1);
```

OR

```
Alter table ServiceDetails 
  Add  OCF_Internal_ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL default newid();
```

Then run this do define a primary key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE ServiceDetails  
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ServiceDetails_OCF_Internal_ID  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (OCF_Internal_ID);
GO
```